# Ubuntu 12.10 on Eee PC 1000?

Tags: 12.10, unity-2d, eeepc

I have an old Asus netbook (an Eee PC 1000) that has been a traveling companion of mine for quite some time.  I installed Ubuntu on it after I bought it back in 2008, and have been updating it with new releases as they've come out.

My needs for it have always been light: basically a machine for typing, either into LibreOffice, the terminal, or a browser window. For most of its life the Eee has had plenty of power to handle this. But with recent releases it's started to get pretty slow -- it's not uncommon for my typing to outpace the cursor, and browser windows frequently freeze up and gray out on JavaScript-intensive sites -- so I've become more and more hesitant about making updates to avoid making the problem worse.  Currently it's sitting on Ubuntu 11.10.

I've been thinking about bringing it up to date with 12.10, but the slowness problem, combined with 12.10 ditching Unity 2D, makes me wonder if it's really suitable for this old piece of kit. The Eee PC 1000 is pretty weak spec-wise -- Atom CPU, 1GB RAM, Intel GMA 950 integrated graphics. So I'm thinking it may just not be up to running modern versions of Ubuntu, since those have become increasingly GPU-intensive.

The problem is that nobody really makes machines like this one anymore -- the netbook sector has been eaten up by tablets on the low end and ultrabooks on the high end. Plus, call me old fashioned but I hate throwing away a perfectly good machine.

Have any of you tried running 12.10 on an Eee 1000 or a similarly-spec'ed netbook? How did it work out?

Comment: I have not tried it, but you might want to try booting it from usb? If that doesn't work speedwise it might just be because of the USB (so you know nothing), but if it DOES work fast enough (relatively), you might have a chance

Answer (score 2):

My experience with an Eee PC 1215 is that Ubuntu 12.10 with Unity is no fun to use on this machine. Opening the dash or typing in it is sluggish. But I can recommend Ubuntu 12.04 on the 1215 (which has a dual core Atom CPU with 2GB RAM and integrated Intel graphics) which is fast enough for fluid working.

So if you want to upgrade to a more recent Ubuntu try 12.04 which also has long term support.

Comment: My Eee PC 1000H works well with Ubuntu 12.04 in Unity 2D mode.  Very poor performance in 3D mode.  I briefly used 12.10 and had to revert to get back to a usable state.  I agree with the recommendation to use Ubuntu 12.04 or earlier on this hardware.

Answer (score 2):

I am writing from an eee 1000 and I have enjoyed this machine for the past 4 years.

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.10 using the [Minimal CD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD).  The text installer after the basic setup,  will ask for what packages you want to download and install.  I only seleced "Ubuntu Base Server" and "OpenSSH Server", without any Desktop Environment (GNOME, XFCE, etc.).  Then I install my preferred [minimalistic tiling window manager: dwm](http://dwm.suckless.org).

Everything works out of the box (wifi, audio, mic, etc.) and my eee has never been faster.

---

PS: if you are looking for a less radical solution, try [crunchbang linux](http://crunchbanglinux.org), it's a pretty lightweight debian-based distro that runs well on an eee.

Answer (score 1):

Lubuntu seems to be a widely preferred alternative, followed by Xubuntu. I reckon Linux Mint might also run ok.

Answer (score 1):

ubuntu 12.04 with unity 2d has been very good on eeepc 701, unity is amazing on a small screen, you should try it with a live cd/usb and see what you think. DO NOT USE 12.10

Answer (score 0):

EasyPeasy (Formerly Ubuntu Eee or Eeebuntu, I forget which - the other became AuroraOS) seems very nice and snappy for me. I just installed it on my Eee901, which is essentially the same device as yours with a 1.2" smaller screen.

Everything worked straight out of the box, it's fairly responsive - a short pause before opening each program, which is survivable, and battery life seems decent on a 4 year old machine.